# How to set Back Button Title?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have Xamarin Forms Solution and in Xamarin Android project I would like to set back button title. However when I set it, it is not shown. On Help page I am setting back button title:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HelpPage), typeof(HelpPageRenderer_Droid))]
namespace XX.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class HelpPageRenderer_Droid : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            var page = Element as HelpPage;

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, true);

            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(page, "Help");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I push new About Page on navigation stack:

```cs
private async void OpenAboutPage()
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
}
```

As a result, on About page back button is shown, but there is no back button title. What am I doing wrong? Does someone has back button title in their Android app?

Edit: I tried changing order of pages - to put HelpPage on top of AboutPage and title is not shown.
Edit: I also tried changing colors (BarBackgroundColor and BarTextColor) in case title is present but not visible.
I also tried from AboutPage.xaml.cs and HelpPage.xaml.cs to call:

```cs
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "Back");
```

Comment: This answer might help you (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39031427/3580625). It says that the property isn't supported on android and that you need a custom renderer for android.

Comment: It would be great if it can be done in custom renderer, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It is not duplicate. I tried solutions from that question, but it doesn't solve my problem. I'm unable to set back button title text.